# How do I troubleshoot a LibreOffice outline?

Tags: libreoffice

I have a slightly fancy outline in LibreOffice Writer that I use to manage lesson planning.

For every week that the class meets I have a Level 1 header, the line is something like **Jan 31: Welcome** and the outline formatting adds `Week # /` to that so that what actually appears is **Week 1 / Jan 31: Welcome** -- then I use Level 2 headers to break up the class session ("Welcome and Introductions, 30 min").

It works pretty great. I can use the Navigator to move around in the document,  I can print the pages I need to prep for any given week. Fab. But somewhere along the line, I screwed up Week 3. I don't know how I did it, but I can't seem to fix it.

What I have is basically this:

```
Week 1 / Jan 31: Welcome
Week 2 / Feb 07 ...
Week / Feb 14 ...
Week 4 / Feb 21 ...
Week 5 / Feb 28 ...
```

I looked in `tools > Outline Numbering ...` and I don't see anything that would restart the numbering or prevent numbering of item 3. I have the navigator open so I know I don't have any stray Header 1s. Using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to make that header plain text doesn't seem to change the numbering. Neither does changing it back.

I tried adding a new week after Week 2, and that adds it as **Week 3 / ** but when I replace my busted week with it, I just get:

```
Week 1 / Jan 31: Welcome
Week 2 / Feb 07 ...
Week 4 / Feb 14 ...
Week 5 / Feb 21 ...
Week 6 / Feb 28 ...
```

It is like the outline is committed to avoiding **Week 3**. How do I even troubleshoot this?

Comment: This looks like a very localized problem. We would likely have to see a sample file to to help you (just a barebones file with all the passages between the headings removed). Because this question is more about LO than Ubuntu I'd also like to direct you to two very good LO/OO-specific support ressources: [Ask LO](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/) and  [OO forums](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewforum.php?f=7). The folks over at OO forums have always been very helpful whenever I had a strange problem with LO in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glutanimate basically solved it for me.

In trying to save out a bare bones version, I found that when I deleted one whole section, the numbering started working fine. Restore that section, the numbering breaks.

So the problem was that I had some wonky extra line that was not H1 but was numbered like H1 and throwing everything else off.